# Usage guide of treemap from the code

Tags: java, object, treemap, treemaps

```
public class MMTUtil
{
private static Map<String, String> domainDocumentationMap             = null;
 static
    {
     domainDocumentationMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    }

public static Map<String, String> getDomainDocumentationMap() {
    return domainDocumentationMap;
}

public static void setDomainDocumentationMap(Map<String, String> domainDocumentationMap) {
    MMTUtil.domainDocumentationMap = domainDocumentationMap;
}
```

Can you guys help me understand this code ?

How can I use this code to return me domainComboDocumentationMap and domainComboDocumentationMap so that I can use it in another java file ?

```
Edit:



public UMRResultObject insertDocumentation(UMRDocumentationDTO documentationDTO)
{
    Session     session = UMRHibernateUtil.getUmrSession();
    Transaction tx      = null;
    documentationLink = null;
    objectName = null;
    objectType = null;

    try
    {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        dao.insertDocumentation(documentationDTO, session);
********MMTUtil.getDomainDocumentationMap().put(objectName.getDomainName()+objectType.getDomainType(),documentationLink.getDocumentationLink());******
        tx.commit();
        ro.setSuccess(true);
        ro.getMessages().add("Record Inserted Successfully");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MMTUtil is a class with static methods, so you can just use it like this:

`MMTUtil.getDomainComboDocumentationMap()` will return a domainComboDocumentationMap 
`MMTUtil.getDomainDocumentationMap()` will return a domainDocumentationMap

You will need to import `MMTUtil` into the other java file that is using this class.

Comment: I had already imported MMTUtil in my other java fill but I'm still unable to call it

Comment: thanks wasn't calling it from the ejbmodule but rather from MMTWeb 
ahh Sad

Comment: Ah, that's an annoying error. Next time you ask a question, also post some code where you are trying to call it, then we can help spot the error there as well.

Comment: just wrote the code, could you guys help me out please with it